# How do I include a measure of loss in a model of cumulative rate of change?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose you have a tank that has infinitely many taps dripping water into that tank. Each tap slowly increases its rate of dripping, while also losing some drops over the side of the tank.

**First**: the rate of dripping of each tap increases over time, at different rates:

The 1st tap increases by one drop p/s every 1*2 seconds

The 2nd tap increases by one drop p/s every 2*3 seconds

The 3rd tap increases by one drop p/s every 3*4 seconds
…

The nth tap increases by one drop p/s every n*(n+1) seconds

**Second**: there is a constant loss from each tap to take into consideration. For each tap, the first two drops that come out, per second, fail to get into the tank.

As a result, the first tap gets no drops into the tank until second 4 (by which time it’s releasing 3 drops p/s), the second tap gets no drops in until second 12, etc.

Here’s a table of the first 24 seconds and the first three taps, counting the drops that get into the tank each second, to give you an idea:

[image: drops in the tank]

How do I calculate the cumulative rate of change accounting for the loss, so that I can say:

At a given second n, how many drops go into the tank that second?

Answer (score 0):

write the "velocity" in drops per s d/s
v1=1+1/2d/s*t for all times t
v2=1d/s(t-11s) from t=12s to t=18 v2=1d/s(t-11s)+1d/s(t-17s) for t>=18s
v3=...
than ad up the velocities  and calculate v(t) so you will know the d/s in the following s

Comment: thanks trula, but that's not very efficient - how do I calculate the number of drops at second 100001498, for example? !

Comment: like I sad, since your time is greater than 24 you just ad up the three velocities and evaluate it for t=100001498 or I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks trula - the problem is the taps increase until you have infinitely many. So I need a formula that captures how much water will be coming out of all the taps into the tank by that time.